# How to pass events to immediate parent in nested components in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, recursion, vue.js, nested

I am building a tree view as which is recursive and nested. To delete I want to pass an event to its parents using $event. But I am not able to receive the events.

Here is my code so far on JSFiddle. 
https://jsfiddle.net/shishirraven/x4s917au/

```
    Vue.component('treeview', {
      template: `
        <ul class="oye-tree-view" @deleteme="wow()" >
              <li class="open"> {{node_name}} 
                  <div @click="$emit('deleteme')" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Delete</div>
                    <template v-for='(node,index) in nodes' >
                    <treeview   v-model="nodes[index]"  :cindex="index"  ></treeview>
                  </template>
              </li>
      </ul>
    `,
      props: ['value', 'cindex'],
      data: function() {
        return this.value
      },
      methods: {
        wow: function() {
          alert("jello");
        }
      }


    });



    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#treeview',
      data: {
        "treeData": {
          "node_name": "Webfort Technologies",
          "nodes": [{
              "node_name": "Core PHP",
              "nodes": []
            },
            {
              "node_name": "Wordpress",
              "nodes": []
            },
            {
              "node_name": "Joomla",
              "nodes": []
            },
            {
              "node_name": "Drupal",
              "nodes": []
            },
            {
              "node_name": "Android",
              "nodes": []
            },
            {
              "node_name": "iOS",
              "nodes": [{
                  "node_name": "Core PHP",
                  "nodes": []
                },
                {
                  "node_name": "Wordpress",
                  "nodes": []
                },
                {
                  "node_name": "Joomla",
                  "nodes": []
                },
                {
                  "node_name": "Drupal",
                  "nodes": []
                },
                {
                  "node_name": "Android",
                  "nodes": []
                },
                {
                  "node_name": "iOS",
                  "nodes": []
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      methods: {
        firstMethod: function() {

        }
      }
    })
```

For complex communication I found that VueX or Event bus is suggested. But I just want to pass the event to immediate parent and do not want to bubble it. 
Second is that I am not sure how I can delete a node even when I generate an event bus event.

Comment: To make it little easy , you will need to give unique id to each node_name for deleting. `{node_name:'Core PHP', id:1,nodes:[]}`

Answer (score 1):

I would assign unique `ids` to each of the object to identify at what level they reside and search that particular `id` when `deleting`. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanketdhoble/x4s917au/67/)

These are couple of things you need to change.

1) Call `deleteme` emit event on the `treeview` component so the parent can listen to it.
`<treeview @deleteme="callDeleteParent">` .

2) In the treeview component, return blank object `{}` inside `data()`. And use the prop values directly in the dom. This makes sure the DOM is updated everytime the `treeData` value is changed.

```
<ul class="oye-tree-view"  >
      <li class="open"> {{value.node_name}}
          <div @click="deleteit(value.node_name,value.id)" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Delete</div>
          <template v-for='(node,index) in value.nodes' >
            <treeview @deleteme="callDeleteParent"  v-model="node"  :cindex="index"  ></treeview>
          </template>
      </li>
</ul>
```

3) Once event is passed to the parent, you can delete the object using `id` by recursively traversing the array objects to find the `id`.

```
function removeFromTree(parent, childIdToRemove){
    if(parent.id==childIdToRemove){//Webfort Technologies (parent)
       return [];
    }
      parent.nodes = parent.nodes
        .filter(child =>  child.id !== childIdToRemove)
        .map(child => removeFromTree(child, childIdToRemove));
      return parent;
   }
  this.treeData = removeFromTree(this.treeData, obj.id);
```

Find the working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sanketdhoble/x4s917au/67/).